# How to get the desired values from a list of multiple different kind of strings

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, split

I am building a tool to calculate PT accessibility. I just need few more data to start the quantifying process but been struggling for this issue below.

I have this script which can get the break-leg data of public transport trips from HERE API, here is a sample result from the code:

```
a = [' Walk 158m - 160s', ' Walk 267m - 267s', ' bus-246 ', ' bus-302 ', ' NA ', 'GTFS time > HERE API time', ' Walk 556m - 566s', 'train-Lilydale', ' Walk 52m - 52s', 'rail-109', ' Walk 0m - 0s']
```

I only want to get a list of numbers in front of 'm' and 's' in order to calculate total walking time and distance of one trip, I could only get rid of 'm', 's' and 'NA' from adjusting the script and result would look likes this:

```
a = ['158 - 160', ' 267 - 267', ' bus-246 ', ' bus-302 ', 'GTFS time > HERE API time', ' 556 - 566', 'train-Lilydale', ' 52 - 52', 'rail-109', ' 0 - 0']
```

But even if I could get what I want (which I'm unable to), adjusting the exiting script is kind of ugly though.

The point is how to get the outputs in this form:

```
Distance = [158, 267, 556, 52, 0]
Time = [160, 267, 556, 52, 0]
```

So I can then calculate the sum of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a very simple regular expressions:

```py
import re

a = [' Walk 158m - 160s', ' Walk 267m - 267s', ' bus-246 ', ' bus-302 ', ' NA ', 'GTFS time > HERE API time', ' Walk 556m - 566s', 'train-Lilydale', ' Walk 52m - 52s', 'rail-109', ' Walk 0m - 0s']

def number_values(e):
    out = e
    numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', e)
    if len(numbers) == 2:
        out = '{0} - {1}'.format(*numbers)
    return out

[number_values(v) for v in a if v != ' NA ']
```

```py
['158 - 160',
 '267 - 267',
 ' bus-246 ',
 ' bus-302 ',
 'GTFS time > HERE API time',
 '556 - 566',
 'train-Lilydale',
 '52 - 52',
 'rail-109',
 '0 - 0']
```